# Add empty columns at the end of a CSV file

Tags: linux, csv, sed, awk, double-quotes

I have a .CSV file (lets say named as file.csv) with numeric and string values. The string might contain commas hence they are enclosed in double quotes as in the below format.

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7  
12,455,"string, with, quotes, and with, commas, in between",4432,6787,890,88  
4432,6787,"another, string, with, quotes, and, with, multiple, commaz, in between",890,88,12,455  
11,22,"simple, string",77,777,333,22
```

When I am trying to add empty columns at the end of the file, using the below code

```
awk -F, '{NF=13}1' OFS="," file.csv > temp_file.csv
```

the output is not as per my requirement. The code is also counting the commas in the text qualifier fields too whihc are enclosed in double quotes. The output of the file `cat temp_file.csv` using the above command is as below:

```
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,,,,,,  
12,455,"string, with, quotes, and with, commas, in between",4432,6787,890,88,  
4432,6787,"another, string, with, quotes, and, with, multiple, commaz, in between",890,88  
11,22,"simple, string",77,777,333,22,,,,,
```

Where as I need the total number of fields in the field to be 13. Any input on this issue using either **`awk`** or **`sed`** is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have control over the CSV generation?  If so, can you use a different field separator (like |) ?

Comment: You have lots of spaces at the end of the file.

Comment: @Nirk I do not generate the CSV. I get it from one of the customers.

Comment: @Jotne THe trailing spaces are due to the code sample rules in this forum, I mean to create a new line in the code sample. I had to give two spaces to move the data in the next line.

Comment: If you like to threat double quotes `"` as one filed, you have a serious programming to do.  Do a google search for csv and awk.  It may be faster to import the file in excel and fix it there.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '{sub(/ *$/,"");$0=$0 ","}1' OFS=,
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,
12,455,"string, with, quotes, and with, commas, in between",4432,6787,890,88,
4432,6787,"another, string, with, quotes, and, with, multiple, commaz, in between",890,88,12,455,
11,22,"simple, string",77,777,333,22,
```

This removes trailing space and add one filed at the end.

Answer (score -1):

If your input always has 7 fields as posted then take your pick:

```
awk '{print $0 ",,,,,,"}' file
sed 's/$/,,,,,,/' file
```

or to remove trailing spaces:

```
awk '{sub(/ *$/,",,,,,,")}1' file
sed 's/ *$/,,,,,,/' file
```

If your input file can have different numbers of fields present but still has the header line as you show:

```
awk -F, 'NR==1{flds=sprintf("%*s",13-NF,""); gsub(/ /,FS,flds)} {sub(/ *$/,flds)} 1' file
column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,column7,,,,,,
12,455,"string, with, quotes, and with, commas, in between",4432,6787,890,88,,,,,,
4432,6787,"another, string, with, quotes, and, with, multiple, commaz, in between",890,88,12,455,,,,,,
11,22,"simple, string",77,777,333,22,,,,,,
```